# Screen sluggish in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics

I have an old assembled PC with

- 2.6 GHz Intel core2 Duo
- 4 GB ram and
- Nvidia Gforce 7100 GS Graphic card.

I tried to Install Ubuntu 14.04. When I tried it before installing it worked smoothly , however when I installed and ran it, the screen was sluggish from the time of login and the mouse cursor took a lot of time to move from one point to another.

When I ran ubuntu 12.04 or lower there were no such issues. Any idea what could be the problem and solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you haven't installed an NVIDIA driver so far. You can easily install them via the **Additional Driver** tab in **Software & Updates**.

The dialog might look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: mine seems to be using X.Org X server ...however screen is still sluggish...

Comment: Well in case you are currently using X.Org X Server and have issues - consider testing one of the NVIDIA drivers (as written in my initial answer)

Comment: that seemed to have done the job....thank you...

Comment: Great to hear - please mark your post as answered then and enjoy your better performance ;)